# Matrix Differential equation x'(t) = Ax(t)+b solution defined for non-invertible values

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

The problem I am trying to find a solution for is this linear ODE, where A is an $n x n$ matrix and b is an $nx1$ matrix.

$$x'(t) = Ax(t) + b$$

One solution for this equation is provided by a wikipedia article:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation#Stability_and_steady_state_of_the_matrix_system

$$x^* = -A^{-1} b$$
$$x(t) = x^* + e^{At}(x(0) - x^*)$$

The biggest trouble I am running into is that, in my case, $A$ may be singular. In which case, this solution won't work.

One thing I noticed: if this were a scalar problem, not a matrix problem, and A were non-invertible, than A would have to be zero. If I set A to zero in my original equation, I get the following.

$$x'(t) = 0x(t) + b$$
$$x'(t) = b$$
$$x(t) = bt + x(0)$$

This tells me that the solution I seek should resolve to $x(t) = bt + x(0)$ if $A$ is the zero matrix.

How can I determine the solution to this equation when $A$ is singular, but not zero? Is there a way to take the limit of $x(t)=x^∗+e^{At}(x(0)−x^∗)$ so that it is defined when $A$ is singular?

Comment: Is $A$ diagonalizable? If so you can decouple your problem into $n$ scalar equations using an eigenvalue decomposition. The equations corresponding to zero eigenvalues are solved as you suggest. The remaining ones are solved in the Wikipedia way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general solution is the general homogeneous solution plus a particular solution. A very convenient particular solution is a stationary solution. In this problem, a stationary solution $x^*$ is any solution to $Ax^*=-b$. If a stationary solution exists, then the general solution is $x=e^{At}y+x^*$ as $y$ ranges over all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here in general $y \neq x(0)$. However, $e^{At}$ is always invertible. Therefore you can always find $y$ to fit to whatever initial condition you want.

This approach can be viewed as being equivalent to what we usually do in the nonnlinear case: $x'=Ax+b$ is equivalent to $(x-x^*)'=A(x-x^*)$, so you solve for $x-x^*$ and add $x^*$ back at the end.

Whether a stationary solution exists or not, and in fact whether the forcing is constant or not, a solution to $x'(t)=Ax(t)+f(t)$ is

$$x(t)=\int_0^t e^{As} f(t-s) ds.$$

In this case $f(t-s) \equiv b$, so we have

$$x(t)=\int_0^t e^{As} b ds.$$

Thus overall the general solution to $x'=Ax+b$ is

$$x(t)=e^{At}y+\int_0^t e^{As}b ds$$

as $y$ ranges over all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Note that in this form actually $y=x(0)$, which is not the case for the form from the first paragraph.

Comment: Why do you choose $y(0) = b$ as IVP?

Comment: @Evgeny $e^{As}b=y(s)$ where $y'=Ay,y(0)=b$. I edited the answer to make this more explicit.

Comment: Thanks! This answers a lot of problems I have been fighting with the past few days. One more thing, though. In my case I need to be able to evaluate this in a python script, given A and b. The only way I can think of to evaluate that final integral is with u substitution, which doesn't seem to work since I run into the same problem of not being able to resolve $A^{-1}$. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @computer-whisperer If you want an explicit formula, you should use the Jordan normal form of $A$ (usually, the eigenvalue decomposition of $A$) to get an explicit formula for $e^{At}$. Then the integrals are pretty straightforward (at worst you might have to do some integration by parts). Numerically, you can compute $e^{As} b$ by numerically solving $y'=Ay,y(0)=b$ and then integrate your numerical solution.

Comment: @Ian Please forgive my ignorance (I am currently taking calc 1, haven't gotten to integration by parts) but could you help me through understanding your solution to the integration?

Answer (score 0):

In response to your nice observation when $x$ and $y$ are $1×1$ matrices, we could multiply with cofactor of $A$ to simplify the system. since $A$ cofactor $A$ is $\det A\,I$ is $0$ when $A$ is singular,
$$\newcommand{\cof}{\operatorname{cof}}
\cof A\,x'(t)= \cof A\, B\\
\cof A\,(x'(t)-B)=0
$$
Let's take 2 cases,

- Case 1.
  $\cof A$ is not $0$. in that case $x'(t)-B$ must be $0$ which we know how to solve.
- Case 2.
  $\cof A=0$. any function is ok as the second bracket can be anything